# AWS: How to Block IP making more than 1 request per second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I am hosting a monolith web app in AWS. In my web app, there are 2 heavy pages which load complicated dataset by running 3 heavy MySQL queries. From time to time, some authenticated user of my system ends up making more than 1 request/second to those pages using a browser plugin. Thus this hampers server performance and slows down other users of the system. I know a bit about `AWS WAF`. Is there any way to detect such behavior and block such an IP address automatically and not slow down other users? Any suggestions would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Presumably you can correlate this to a login session and you have a way to communicate with the user via the app or email. May be worth reaching out to understand why this is happening. Aside from WAF options, you could also implement server-side throttling based on client IP.

Comment: I know why they use such a plugin. the problem is, they use that plugin for some other page but at some point, they end up one of these 2 heavy pages and forget to disable the plugin and thus create this issue. :(

Do you think server-side throttling will help out? I am using Nginx BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WAF rate-based rule, it is based upon a maximum number of requests in a 5 minute period.

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/limits.html) the current limit is 100. Once more than 100 requests have been hit the IP will receive a 403 until their 5 minute request count is below this number.

For more information read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-rate-based.html

Comment: i also came to this link you provided, but didn't understand much TBH

Comment: So effectively, add this as a rule on the AWS WAF, if you don't want people to perform more than 1 request a second the rate limit value is 1X300 (300 requests in 300 seconds).

If a user performs more than 300 requests within a sliding window of 300 seconds they will receive a 403 until their request count in a 300 second sliding window decreases below the limit

Comment: i will take a look and play around with it.